# Does anyone know why content-md5 is being removed in the HTTP 1.1 update?

Tags: http, http-headers, rfc

I'm not overly concerned with it, as it doesn't stop you from using the header (and it's not one I typically use anyway) but it seemed rather arbitrary and I'm wondering if there's something there I'm not considering. I can't seem to find any notes on the decision, however.

Does anyone have any information on this?

Answer (score 1):

No sooner did I ask, than I found it. I was reading an abridged RFC apparently. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231

> > The Content-MD5 header field has been removed because it was
> > inconsistently implemented with respect to partial responses.